# How do I use Yodlee's Aggregation API with OAuth?

Tags: yodlee

Yodlee has a [getOAuthAccessToken](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getOAuthAccessToken) API call.

When calling `getOAuthAccessToken` with a valid `cobSessionToken` and `userSessionToken`, it returns a response that looks something like this:

```
{
   "token":"985db1c266544028ad0caad43d40460a",
   "tokenSecret":"1fd3981c8d00404eb1ff184f2788a5a6",
   "tokenLiveTime":3600,
   "tokenCreationTime":1382681683679,
   "bridgetKeyData":{
       "bridgetAppId":10003200
   },
   "memId":11903865
}
```

Given that it is documented as part of the Aggregation API, it seems to be implying that I can call the other aggregation API methods using an OAuth token as an alternative to using the `cobSessionToken` and `userSessionToken` parameters.

Is this indeed possible?  If so, what unit of time is `tokenLiveTime` is expressed in?

Answer (score 0):

This getOauthToken API is used to invoke the Fastlink application.
Fastlink Application is a Yodlee hosted app, which could be invoked to you website and allows the consumers to search a particular site and do an add account. This safe time and effort of the customers/developers for building a UI for consumers to add an account.

This API is not intended to use as an alternative to cobSessionToken/userSessionToken.

You can find more about the Fastlink [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/FastLink_for_Aggregation).

The tokenLiveTime is in seconds.